# Benchtop circuit breaker

Tags: power-supply, mains, fuses

I repair electric appliances and tools. Every once in a while, the main circuit breaker trips when I plug in a device. I don't want to prevent a circuit breaker from doing its job, but I would prefer not reset the breaker at the panel every time it happens.

How could I configure this to prevent nuisance panel-breaker trips?
(I don't even know what search terms to use.)

Comment: I would suggest an isolation transformer - it may come with its own breaker.

Comment: Is the main breaker that trips, the Earth Leakage / RCCI, or just the overcurrent breaker?

Comment: I have requested that this be re-opened. It was closed because the OP used the word 'purchase' in it. The question is clearly a good design question to solve a practical problem, would be of interest to many and several of the answers give design suggestions. OP edited to remove 'purchase'.

Comment: This could be a really convenient idea: E.g., maybe I want the option of connecting my work to receptacles protected by 5A, 10A, or 15A, plus some that are thermal-trip only, some magnetic, some GFCI, and some arc-fault.  I can't find any "work-box" mounted breakers I could put right next to the indicated receptacle to facilitate this.  I could do a sub-panel with a plethora of connections to a receptacle bank, but that would be less elegant and probably more expensive.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4jeI2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Bench test mains power supply.*

**How it works**

- The transformer XFMR1 is a 1:1 mains power transformer. You need to figure out what's the most powerful appliance you need to test and size accordingly. e.g., for 1000 W use a 1000 VA transformer.
- The transformer will isolate the load from the mains and if there is an earth leakage fault on the appliance it will prevent your main RCD and the one on this setup from tripping. (More later.) It will also protect you while the EARTH TEST switch is open.
- The lamp serves as a current limiting test device. Open the FULL ON switch before you plug in the device. The brightness of the lamp will give an indication of the current draw. If it goes to full brightness on a small appliance, for example, you may have a short circuit but current will be limited to 0.5 A (230 V AC lamp) or 1 A (120 V AC lamp). If all appears well then switch FULL ON.
- If all is well then close the EARTH TEST fault switch. Now if there is an earth fault on the appliance some of the current will return on the earth-wire instead of the neutral (N). The RCD will detect a difference between the L and N current and trip out. This would usually only trip if there's an earth fault to a metal-cased appliance.
- Size the RCD (current rating) to protect the transformer.

That should help you sort out most problems on the bench.

Comment: The series lamp is a good idea, though care should be taken that the voltage drop of the lamp due to the device current draw does not cause issues such as intermittent resets in a critical controller. I would not recommend isolating the circuit and building a basic+earth fault protection again, unless it is proven the breaker trips because of earth leakage.

Comment: Ramping up the current might be necessary, if the inrush current is the root cause and the lamp does not allow a soft start.

Comment: _"I repair electric appliances and tools."_ I think he'll be fine for this application, but point taken. I've used this technique on industrial servo drives during SMPS repair. I don't understand your second sentence.

Comment: Well, unless it is proven the breaker trips because of a fault (leakage outside of the two lines, generally to earth), I can't see the point of isolating the circuit and providing the same sort of protection which is upstream of the transformer. Without more information, it could simply be high inrush currents ("when I plug in a device"), which can be solved by limiting the inrush current and adding a faster breaker.

Comment: @MisterMystère: The idea is that with the isolation transformer the upstream RCD will _never_ trip - even with a faulty device. (This is in the user requirement specifications of the OP to avoid having to leave the bench.) The secondary RCD _will_ trip if there is an earth fault when the EARTH TEST switch is closed. Does that make sense?

Comment: I have understood the purpose of the isolation transformer in case of earth faults. I'm just saying this may not be necessary, if the devices have been tripping the DB's breakers for different reasons (e.g. inrush current), as it seems to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

There are **miniature circuit breakers** that have both input-side and output-side screw terminals. Din rail mounting may be the most popular, but you might find some that are panel mounted. They are intended for mounting inside an enclosure, but they likely have screw terminals that are sufficiently protected for open mounting in an area that is accessible only by you or other qualified personnel. There may also be some that can be mounted in the face of a small enclosure. There are **molded case circuit breakers** that are intended for panel mounting but can be mounted in the face of an enclosure.

You should probably get a breaker that has magnetic trip. I suspect that the ones in outlet strips have thermal trip only. I have seen some workbench outlet strips. You might want to find those and see what they have built into them.

I should have said you should definitely get a breaker with magnetic trip because the main breaker has magnetic trip and you need the local breaker to trip first. Of course, you need the trip rating of the local breaker to be lower or faster. You will need to look at the curves to coordinate them properly.

Comment: What about GCFI? Any issues?

Comment: If your main circuit breaker is a GFCI breaker, there is no problem putting a smaller breaker at your bench. However if you have a ground fault, you will still need to go to the main panel to reset it. If you don't have GFCI protection, you add it by putting a GFCI outlet in a box at the bench. You might find a miniature circuit breaker that includes GFCI protection.

Comment: No circuit breaker, fast or slow, can definitely stop the next one in the chain from tripping. If you apply a solid short circuit, you can trip all the way to the street. A massive short will draw several kA, and all the breakers in the row will start to trip. Even if your bench one opens within a half cycle, the others may already have enough momentum to open. I've tripped a 100 and a 250 A breaker upstream, from a 30 A circuit.

Comment: Agreed. There are no guarantees. You need to do the best you can with the breaker selection and hope there is enough impedance in the fault path.

Answer (score 0):

Just get one of these : -

[image]

And stick it in a box. Then mount the box on your bench.

Or buy an AC socket outlet with a breaker built in.

Comment: I think you should mention that the trip time is of importance: the concept of "discrimination" is all about selecting the right trip characteristic to make sure the breakers downstream trigger before the ones in the distribution board. Otherwise there is no guarantee the DB's are not going to trip before or at the same time.

Comment: That looks perfect, but what is that called?

Comment: It's a circuit breaker.

Comment: But I've never seen a circuit breaker with faceplate screws.  I can't see the back of that, but if it's a bus-mount breaker then it requires a distribution panel.  If it has screw connectors for direct connection of both service and load wires then it could go in a work box and meets the objectives of the OP quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of power strips (at least those sold in North America, China is different) have circuit breakers built in. Using one of those would be one of the least expensive approaches, plus you have a power switch (though you shouldn't depend on that for safety).

[image]

Chances are it would blow before the mains circuit breaker. You should consider installing a GFCI (RCD) outlet as well.

One technique I use sometimes when troubleshooting relatively low power devices such as electronic devices with a switching supply is to wire a light bulb such as 100W incandescent in series with the DUT. If the light bulb goes on, there is still a problem. Of course this won't work with anything that draws a lot of current normally.

Comment: Sometimes they trip and other times they don't.

Comment: @user148298 If less than the circuit amperage is required, the cb in the strip above could be swapped out. In particular the OP would want the 'magnetic' type not the thermal type.